# Restriction on canvas area for Drawing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

in html ,i have created  canvas on which i am load picture suppose mobile picture , now on canvas i want to restric user fro drawing . fabricjs i using to draw element which should be drawn only in drawn area , how can i restic it ??

HTML code:

```
<canvas id="design_text"  style="border:1px solid #000000; ">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('design_text');
```

Comment: I don't think restricting the user is the best solution. You could have a smaller canvas and place the image a little bit outside of it, or you could cover part of the canvas with some other elements.

Comment: @JonasGrumann after drawing i need to save canvas with background image . thats why i need to set bg of canvas with image

Comment: You could save only the wanted part of the canvas as a background image. You can create another invisible canvas and copy the desired part of the first one on it. Then you convert the second canvas to image.

Comment: Please check my answer in this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632358/avoid-overflow-in-clip-area-from-canvas-fabricjs

Comment: Did you find any solution if yes please post answer here. I am doing same